# How to integrate $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{x^2 - 1}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{1}^{e}\frac{x^2 - 1}{x}dx$$

I tried to integrate it by splitting the numerator. I get undefined as my final answer. Any help would be super appreciated.

Edit: The lower limit was 1. My apologies

Thanks, 
SG

Comment: I don't understand your issue, or I see it too well... $\dfrac{x^2-1}{x}=x-\dfrac 1x$, for $x \neq 0$...

Comment: Simple long division works.

Comment: Are you sure the lower limit is zero?  It might be 1.

Comment: That was the error, the lower limit was 1. Thanks! How did you figure it out though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^e \frac{x^2-1}xdx
&=\!\int_1^e \frac{x^2}xdx-\int_1^e \frac{1}xdx \\
&=\int_1^e x \:dx-\int_1^e \frac{1}xdx\\
&=\left[\frac{x^2}2-\ln |x|\right]_1^e\\
&=\frac{e^2}2-\frac{3}2\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

This integral is not improper, so you shouldn't get undefined. $$\begin{align}\int_1^e \frac{x^2 - 1}{x}\text{d}x =\int_1^e x-\frac{1}{x}\text{d}x \\ =  \left[\frac{1}{2}x^2-\ln|x|\right]_1^e \\ = \frac{1}{2}e^2-\ln|e|-\left(\frac{1}{2}1^2-\ln|1|\right) \\ = \frac{1}{2}e^2-1-\frac{1}{2}+0 \\ = \frac{1}{2}e^2-\frac{3}{2} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

As an improper integral we may write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^e \frac{x^2-1}{x} dx &=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^e \frac{x^2-1}{x} dx \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\frac12 (e^2- \epsilon^2) -(\log e -\log \epsilon)  \right) \\
&=- \infty
\end{align}$$

Thus, the integral diverges.

Edit after the OP edit.

Replace $\epsilon$ by $1$ in the previous answer to reveal

$$\int_1^e \frac{x^2-1}{x} dx=\frac12(e^2-1) -(\log e -\log 1) =\frac12(e^2-3)$$

Comment: It is apparent that the OP originally meant 1. You can remove the first part of your answer for clarity.